# Laravel: How to allow a route group to be public?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I'm new to Laravel `5.6` and are trying to write an API with the **public route** `/signup`.

For JWT auth, I'm using [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) `1.0.0-rc.2`.

**routes/api.php**

```
// This code WORKS, the route is public
Route::middleware('guest:api')->get('/signup', function(Request $request) {
    return "Sign up"; // This code belongs in the controller
});

// This code DOES NOT WORK, authentification needed
Route::get('signup', 'AuthController@signup')->middleware('guest');

// This code DOES NOT WORK
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'guest:api'
], function($router) {
    Route::get('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
});
```

I couldn't find anything useful in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing), but it should be my wrong way of adding the `guest` permission, as the first example works.

How can I make the the not working code work? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean "This code DOES NOT WORK"? Are you getting any errrors? What is the expected and actual behaviour?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo as mentioned, I want the **route to be public** but only the first one shows "Sign up", the other ones don't allow access if **not authorized**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::middleware(['guest:api'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    Route::get('mySecondRoute', 'AuthController@mySecondFunction');
});
```

or even just

```
Route::get('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
```

out of any group

Comment: Thank you! Another solution that should be placed in the controllers `__construct()`: `$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'signup']]);`.